# Errors with obtaining and reading data from a file

Tags: python, file, search, csv

I'm trying to create a program that reads information about cinema times from a `.csv` file, where the user can search for movie times by the month it is shown, the company producing the movie and the name of the movie.

The file is formatted like:

`Movie name, date , cinema, post code of cinema, company producing, cost`

for each line.

The only information that I need to search for are the dates, company producing and the name of the movie.

The first problem I have with this code is, when I search for movies by a company, only the first movie by the company in the file is shown and I want to show all of them.

The second problem I have is that I need to search for movies by month, but the format for date in the file is `dd/mm/yy` and I am not sure how to search for just the month and ignore the day and year.

If anyone has a solution to either of these problems, I would very much appreciate it and thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you paste part of your input file as an example?

Comment: The first one is Frozen,03/04/2014,IMAX,LN3 6SD,Disney,£5.49

Comment: This line looks fine, although look out for extra spaces in other lines. If you see some, you can handle them in your code with the `strip` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem it seems that your code is correct, I've tested it out and it does indeed print a list where there is a match for company:

```
>>> company = "one"
>>> moviedata = [("one","two"), ("two","one"), ("two","three")]
>>> print([s for s in moviedata if (company) in s])
[('one', 'two'), ('two', 'one')]
```

I can only suggest to print out and check if your moviedata is stored in list of tuples.

for second problem just slice the data you have to retrieve the month:

```
>>> "03/04/2014"[3:5]
'04'
```

example for your code:

```
>>> moviedata = [("one","two"), ("two","one"), ("two","three")]
>>> moviedata[1]
('two', 'one')
>>> moviedata[1][1]
'one'
>>> moviedata[1][1][:2]
'on'
```

Comment: I get more than one result by printing that now, though I didn't before. I'm not sure how it works, but thanks for helping e with that problem.

Comment: for your second problem just slice the date to get the month, edited the code part on my comment.

Comment: I've attempted that, but the problem is that each line is read as an element, so moviedata[0:3] returns the first three lines of the file.

Comment: you need to get the element and then slice it, try moviedata[2][3:5] or moviedata[2][0:3] if month is the first number(borken american format ^^) edited an example in.